# Selecting every image of collection using Google Earth Engine?

Tags: google-earth-engine

I am currently working on google earth engine and I have created an image collection with 15 images in it. What i want to do is to create an image for every single image in my collection. I was able to create an image for the first image of my collection by doing :

```
var Image1 = ee.Image(Collection.first());
```

Although i would like to do that for the 15 images. Is there any way to do a loop that reads the entire collection and creates images by iterating. The first one would be Image1, and then Image2, Image3 and so on...

Comment: Did you check the google group for google earth engine? This question has been answered there.

Comment: ohh i'm sorry, i did not know this was a thing. Thank you very much.

Comment: There's a lot of group for google earth engine. Can you tell me the exact name of the group you are talking about please. This help would be very much appreciated

Comment: google-earth-engine-developers@googlegroups.com

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think that the easiest way to do it is to transform the image collection into a List.

```
var listOfImages = myCollection.toList(myCollection.size());
```

and access each image using indices, like:

```
var img1 = listOfImages[0];
var img2 = listOfImages[1];
```

Comment: This syntax no longer works, hence outdated.

Answer (score 21):

I think instead of accessing the images by this syntax: `list[index]`, you should use the `get()` method.

e.g.

```
var listOfImages = myCollection.toList(myCollection.size());
var firstImage = listOfImages.get(0)
var secondImage = listOfImages.get(1)
var lastImage = listOfImages.get(listOfImages.length().subtract(1));

// Type Cast Image for using ee.Image() function
var listOfImages = ee.Image(myCollection.toList(myCollection.size()));
var firstImage = ee.Image(listOfImages.get(0));
var secondImage = ee.Image(listOfImages.get(1));
var lastImage = ee.Image(listOfImages.get(listOfImages.length().subtract(1)));

// Now you can use ee.Image functions 
var B2 = firstImage.select("B2")
```

Comment: this is the right answer ...

Answer (score 4):

It's recommended to use sytax as below:

```
var listOfImages = myCollection.toList(myCollection.size());
var img1 = listOfImages.get(0);
var img2 = listOfImages.get(1);
```

It seemed to be correct but not the best way, as in this way, you **are not able** to use functions of `myCollection`, eg. `img1.select()` would be illegal. To avoid this, use syntax as below:

```
var listOfImages = myCollection.toList(myCollection.size());
var img1 = ee.Image(listOfImages.get(0));
var img2 = ee.Image(listOfImages.get(1));
```

Then all the functions provided by `myCollection` can be utilized normally.

Comment: Thanks for reminding this.

Answer (score 2):

I think mohit kaushik's suggestion is better. In addition, add `ee.Image` at first to select this as image format, e.g.,

// Typecast element as earth engine image
var firstImage = ee.Image(listOfImages.get(0));