# Layer error: Element.get, argument 'property': Invalid type. Expected: String. Actual: Integer

Tags: google-earth-engine

I have a code that calculates NDVI for an imageCollection and then is supposed to display those rasters. The rasters are filtered by their size so only rasters that have more than a certain amount of pixels are being added to a new imageCollection and then displayed.
The problem is that the images cannot be displayed and I get the next error message:

> Layer error: Element.get, argument 'property': Invalid type. Expected:
> String. Actual: Integer

The graphs are displayed but the images are not and I don't understand why would the images need to be string, when did they changed and how to change them back to integer.

This is my code:

```
/**
 * Function to mask clouds based on the pixel_qa band of Landsat SR data.
 * @param {ee.Image} image Input Landsat SR image
 * @return {ee.Image} Cloudmasked Landsat image
 */
var cloudMaskL457 = function(image) {
  var qa = image.select('pixel_qa');
  // If the cloud bit (5) is set and the cloud confidence (7) is high
  // or the cloud shadow bit is set (3), then it's a bad pixel.
  var cloud = qa.bitwiseAnd(1 << 5)
                  .and(qa.bitwiseAnd(1 << 7))
                  .or(qa.bitwiseAnd(1 << 3));
  // Remove edge pixels that don't occur in all bands
  var mask2 = image.mask().reduce(ee.Reducer.min());
  return image.updateMask(cloud.not()).updateMask(mask2).divide(10000)
  .copyProperties(image, ['system:time_start']);
};

//Create LANDSAT7 dataset

var dataset = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LE07/C01/T1_SR')
                  .filterDate('1999-01-01', '2013-04-29')
                  .select('B1','B2','B3','B4','pixel_qa')
                  .filterBounds(geometry)
                  .map(cloudMaskL457);




//RGB visualization

var visParams = {
  bands: ['B3', 'B2', 'B1'],
  min: 0,
  max: 1,
  gamma: 1.4,
};


//clip the dataset according to the geometry
var clippedCol=dataset.map(function(im){ 
  return im.clip(geometry);
});

// Get the number of images.
var count = dataset.size();
print('Count: ',count);
//print(clippedCol);
print(dataset,'dataset');

//function to calculate NDWI in LANDSAT7
var addNDVI = function(image) {
  var NDVI = image.normalizedDifference(['B4', 'B3'])
  .rename('NDVI')
  .copyProperties(image,['system:time_start']);
  return image.addBands(NDVI);

};

//NDWI to the clipped image collection
var withNDVI = clippedCol.map(addNDVI).select('NDVI');

var NDVIcolor = {
  min: -1,
  max:1,
  palette: ['FFFFFF', 'CE7E45', 'DF923D', 'F1B555', 'FCD163', '99B718', '74A901',
    '66A000', '529400', '3E8601', '207401', '056201', '004C00', '023B01',
    '012E01', '011D01', '011301'],
    
    
    
    
};


var ndviWithCount = withNDVI.map(function(image){
  var countpixels = ee.Number(image.reduceRegion({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.count(),
  geometry: geometry,
  crs: 'EPSG:4326',
  scale: 30,
  }).get('NDVI'));

  return image.set('count', countpixels);
});

print(ndviWithCount, 'ndviWithCount');

//filter between a range
var filter = ndviWithCount.filter(ee.Filter.rangeContains(
          'count', 220000, 446224))
print(filter, 'filtered');

var max = ndviWithCount.reduceColumns(ee.Reducer.max(),  ["count"])
print(max.get('max'));


var OrderList=[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]


for (var i in OrderList) {
  var image = ee.Image(filter.get(OrderList[i]));
  var toexport=image.visualize(NDVIcolor).addBands(image);
 

  // do what ever you need with image
  Map.addLayer(image, NDVIcolor, i);


  
 }


print(ui.Chart.image.series(filter, geometry, ee.Reducer.mean(), 30));
print(ui.Chart.image.series(withNDVI, geometry, ee.Reducer.max(), 30));
print(ui.Chart.image.series(withNDVI, geometry, ee.Reducer.min(), 30));
print(ui.Chart.image.series(withNDVI, geometry, ee.Reducer.stdDev(), 30));
```

Comment: I couldn't get your script to work. I think .get() near the end of your scripts wants a property name, so an integer won't work. You might be able to do something like .get('system:index',  OrderList[i]) but I'm not sure what the properties look like for the image collection 'filter'. Another option might be to cast your image collection as a list and then use the index to select each image.  See here https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/231333/selecting-every-image-of-collection-using-google-earth-engine

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Convert the `filter` ImageCollection to a List of images.

When the `get` method is applied to an ImageCollection it expects the name (string) of a property to get; when it is applied to a List, it expects an integer index value and returns the respective image from the List.

`filter = filter.toList(filter.size()); // convert ImageCollection to List`

See line 97: https://code.earthengine.google.com/e4f2efb32d16a45e918a5ff60ab78b03

Note, however, that converting collections to lists can negatively affect performance. Avoid using `.toList()` if you can use alternative methods. For instance, use `.filter()` to select and image of interest.