# Error while adding all layers to the map in console in Google Earth Engine

Tags: raster, google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I want to add the layer to map,

[followed this solution,](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/340340/layer-error-element-get-argument-property-invalid-type-expected-string-a)

but encountering the following error,

however I have converted the variable value to string, still, it is showing the error:

```
layer error: Element.get, argument 'property': Invalid type.
Expected type: String.
Actual type: Integer.
Actual value: 7
```

[The code is at this link](https://code.earthengine.google.com/b306fc2c7241ca441a8a5b9562b93e88)

```
var shapefile_to_select = Arvind_Punjab

// Function to cloud mask Landsat 8.
var CloudMaskOfLANDSAT8 = function(image) {
  var cloudShadowBitMask = ee.Number(2).pow(3).int();
  var cloudsBitMask = ee.Number(2).pow(4).int();
  var qa = image.select('QA_PIXEL');
  var mask = qa.bitwiseAnd(cloudShadowBitMask).eq(0).and(
            qa.bitwiseAnd(cloudsBitMask).eq(0));
  return image
      .select('SR_B.').multiply(0.0000275).add(-0.2)
      .updateMask(mask)
      .set('system:time_start', image.get('system:time_start'));
};

var startDate = '2021-01-01'
var endDate = '2021-01-31'

var raw_dataset = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C02/T1_L2')

var cloudmasked_dataset = raw_dataset
                          .filterDate(startDate, endDate)
                          .filterBounds(shapefile_to_select)  
                          .map(CloudMaskOfLANDSAT8)
                          .map(function(image){return image.clip(shapefile_to_select)});

var colour_Palette = ['#a50026','#d73027','#f46d43','#fdae61',
  '#fee08b','#d9ef8b','#a6d96a','#66bd63','#1a9850','#006837'];


var colList = cloudmasked_dataset.toList(cloudmasked_dataset.size());
var n = colList.size().getInfo();

for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
      
      var img = ee.Image(colList.get(i));
      var id = img.id().getInfo();
      var listOfImages = cloudmasked_dataset.toList(cloudmasked_dataset.size());
      var Tile = listOfImages.get(i);
      var allRasters = ee.ImageCollection.fromImages([Tile]);
      print("Raster no " + i, allRasters)
      
      var console_image = ee.Image(allRasters.get(i));
      Map.addLayer(console_image.select('SR_B2')
                             .clip(shapefile_to_select), 
                            {min:0, max:1,  
                            'palette': colour_Palette}, 
                            i.toString())
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your only intention is to add every Image to the map, these lines are not needed:

```
var allRasters = ee.ImageCollection.fromImages([Tile]);
print("Raster no " + i, allRasters)
var console_image = ee.Image(allRasters.get(i));
```

and you can just do:

```
Map.addLayer(Tile.select('SR_B2').clip(shapefile_to_select), 
             {min:0, max:1,'palette': colour_Palette}, 
             i.toString())
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/a950b6832b27384e9cb88dd1cb3f4e25

If you need to keep the collection for another purpose you can filter the image using the id you get a few lines back, by doing:

```
var allRasters = ee.ImageCollection.fromImages([Tile]);
print("Raster no " + i, allRasters)
var console_image = ee.Image(allRasters.filter(ee.Filter.eq('system:index', id)).first());
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/64d2047ea2eb2c9417cb9f60377e0810